# unable to access method in class inside App_Code for VS2008

Tags: c#, class, app-code

i created a web site in VS2008, in App_Code folder i added a class

```
namespace irfulabs
{
    [DataObject(true)]
    public static class fooDALC
    {
        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public static IList<Screen> Getfoo()
        {

            //Do something
        }


        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
        public static void Insert(Screen src)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
        public static void Update(Screen src)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
        public static void Delete(Screen src)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

on page load event i call the method

```
using irfulabs;

GridView1.DataSource = fooDALC.Getfoo();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and i received the error message "CS0103: The name 'fooDALC' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no issue with code, after setting application folder and virtual directory on my web hosting, page opened without error.